# AddHostedService() is not starting the background services in .net core 3.1, when started from the exe but, works in debug mode from visual studio2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have a host service that only calls another method to do some work like data loading from Db etc before service is running

```
public class HostSoftwareUpdateService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ISoftwareUpdateService _softwareUpdateService;
    public HostSoftwareUpdateService(ISoftwareUpdateService softwareUpdateService)
    {
        _softwareUpdateService = softwareUpdateService;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _softwareUpdateService.Start();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _softwareUpdateService.Stop();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and have added it in start-up as:

```
services.AddHostedService<HostSoftwareUpdateService>();
```

and Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        hostBuilder
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => _ = webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
        hostBuilder.UseWindowsService();
        var host = hostBuilder.Build();
        host.Run();
    }
```

and appsetting.json as:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "urls": "http://*:5014"
}
```

and launch setting:

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5014",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "RemotePatching": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5014"
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm using Kestral by default.

when I try to start the web API using a generated exe, post-build, HostSoftwareUpdateService is not starting. But when I try to debug with Kestral settings HostSoftwareUpdateService is starting.

this exe is not hosted on iis.
am I missing any configuration? which is not letting HostSoftwareUpdateService to start when we run via exe.

Comment: `AddHostedService` only adds the service to your container - it doesn't actually start it.

Comment: If you're using `hostBuilder.UseWindowsService();` then where are you registering your image/process with Windows Service Control Manager? Where are you processing SCM messages/events?

Comment: `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` - is the API you presumably exposing available when you start it using the generated exe? How do you determine that `HostSoftwareUpdateService` is not starting? Do you have other hosted services in the app? Do you have a [mre] we can actually try?

Comment: i have added few logs in _softwareUpdateService.Start() which is getting printed only when i am running the RemotePatching profile in debug mode

Comment: i haven't registered it in Windows Service Control Manager, I am running it as an independent exe by listening to a port 5014 for incoming API request

Comment: @SandhyaRatan In which case you should remove `hostBuilder.UseWindowsService();` entirely.

Comment: Update: the dependent logging ms was running after the above-mentioned service. after fixing the steps to start the microservice its working.
Thank you, everyone!!